# How does Instantiating ObjectA into ObjectB work? And what happens here?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm new to java so this question might seem to have an obvious answer to some, but it's giving me some trouble.

If I have

`ClassA` and `ClassB`

and

`ClassB extends ClassA`

what occurs in this code?

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{

    public void foo(){
        ClassA CA = new ClassB();

    }

}
```

From here I can call Methods from `ClassA` via `CA` <-- this part makes sense.. 
But I'm lost as to..

Why I would ever do this and what the point is and what actually happens.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), but you might like to start an little earlier with [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) ;) ... Yes, it's confusing to start with, but it's very, very powerful and is a core principle to OOP

Comment: `public class TestBikes {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Bicycle bike01, bike02, bike03;

    bike01 = new Bicycle(20, 10, 1);
    bike02 = new MountainBike(20, 10, 5, "Dual");
    bike03 = new RoadBike(40, 20, 8, 23);

    bike01.printDescription();
    bike02.printDescription();
    bike03.printDescription();
  }
}`

clicked your first link and it explained it wonderfully, especially this part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I would ever do this and what the point is

The usual situation where you want to do this is when the code that creates the object and the code that uses the object are not in the same method/class/module, but need to be decoupled a little.

With polymorphism/inheritance you can define an interface for users of the class (`ClassA` in your case), and be able to switch between different implementations (such as `ClassB` in your case) without the calling code needing to know about that.

A canonical example are methods that do something with Collections. Collection is an interface, and there are many different implementations. The calling code can do something with the Collection (for example iterate over the elements) without needing to know if it is an ArrayList or a HashSet.

> and what actually happens.

What happens is that the runtime system seems that the object instance you are calling a method on is an instance of `ClassB`, and it dispatches the code to the right place. This is done without the calling code needing to know about it. For the caller, all that matters is that all methods defined in the interface it wants to have (`ClassA`) are implemented (which the Java compiler makes sure of).

Comment: So can you explain why I cannot use methods that are inside `ClassB`
when I do `ClassA CA = new ClassB()`

`CA` can't access any `ClassB`. From what I'm reading this should be possible.. no?

The only way to do it is to do `ClassB CB = new ClassB();`

But the `Polymorphism` example from oracle shows things like 

`Bycicle bike01 = new MountainBike()`

and it's using `MountainBike` methods via `bike01`, so I'm confused.

Comment: If your variable is of type `ClassA`, then you can access all methods defined in `ClassA`. Nothing more, nothing less. The compiler does not know that the runtime instance is actually of a subclass type with additional methods (because you did not declare it as such). That is the point of a typed language like Java. It allows the compiler to check that these methods really exist (unlike in, say, Perl or Javascript). The downside is that you cannot (easily) call methods that the compiler does not know about.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught polymorphism by example of animals. In practice in doesn't really makes much sense, but it's great to way to understand the principles.

First the correct way:

```
class Animal {
   public void eat() {/* code for eating */};
   public void sleep() {/* code for sleeping */};
}

class Dog extends Animal {
   public void bark() { /* code for barking */ }
}

class Duck extends Animal {
   public void quack() { /* code for quacking */ }
}
```

With this code you can do following:

```
{
   Dog lassie = new Dog();
   Duck donald = new Duck();

   lassie.eat();
   lassie.sleep();
   lassie.bark();
   donald.eat();
   donald.sleep();
   donald.quack();

   List<Animal> barn = new ArrayList<Animal>();
   barn.Add(lassie);
   barn.Add(donald);
}
```

Both `donald` and `lassie` can `eat()` and `sleep()`, because they are both `Animal`s. Each of them makes their own sound, and they can be stuffed together, because they are both `Animal`s.

The counter example would be following code:

```
class Dog {
   public void bark() { /* code for barking */ }
   public void eat() {/* code for eating */};
   public void sleep() {/* code for sleeping */};
}

class Duck {
   public void quack() { /* code for quacking */ }
   public void eat() {/* code for eating same as code in Dog */};
   public void sleep() {/* code for sleeping  same as code in Dog */};
}
```

Now you cannot put both of them in same container, because they are different types. Also you had to write same code twice (`eat`ing and `sleep`ing).

Answer (score 1):

Another usage for this kind of inheritance in when **ClassA** is an **abstract class** that is not implementing some of the functionality, and **ClassB** and some other **ClassC** are **concrete classes** that extend ClassA.

In this case, ClassA implements the common behavior of ClassB and ClassC, and the two classes add their needed functionality.

lets add an example:
**ClassA** is a **Car**, it can drive, turn and stop. all of these actions are implemented in Car, but it's an abstract car.

**ClassB** is a **SportsCar**, it adds the functionality of "Race".

**ClassC** is the **Batmobile**, it add the functionality if "Shoot Rockets From Head Lights".

so, in this example you implement drive,turn and stop ***only once***, 
and add the other Functionality in the inheriting classes.